# Sometimes error are sent to Sentry, sometimes not

Tags: aws-lambda, nestjs, sentry

I create a very simple project in NestJS. One controller which just throws an error:

```
@Controller
export class TestAppController {

  @Get()
  doSmth() {
     throw new Error('Error just happened')
  }
}
```

I created a custom Sentry interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class SentryApiInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private sentryService: SentryService) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    const span = this.sentryService.getRequestSpan(request, {
      op: `Route Handler`,
    });

    return next.handle().pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        const skipCapture =
          error instanceof HttpException && error.getStatus() < 500;
        if (!skipCapture) {
          console.log(`sending error to sentry account`);
          Sentry.captureException(error, span.getTraceContext());
        }
        return throwError(() => error);
      }),
      finalize(async () => {
        span.finish();
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

I have a SentryService:

```
@Injectable()
export class SentryService {
  get span(): Span {
    return Sentry.getCurrentHub().getScope().getSpan();
  }

  public getRequestSpan(request: Request, spanContext: SpanContext) {
    const { method, headers, url } = request;

    const transaction = Sentry.startTransaction({
      name: `Route: ${method} ${url}`,
      op: 'transaction',
    });

    Sentry.getCurrentHub().configureScope((scope) => {
      scope.setSpan(transaction);

      scope.setContext('http', {
        method,
        url,
        headers,
      });
    });

    const span = Sentry.getCurrentHub().getScope().getSpan();

    span.startChild(spanContext);

    return span;
  }

  startChild(spanContext: SpanContext) {
    return this.span.startChild(spanContext);
  }
}
```

I wire it together in module like this:

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    SentryService,
    {
       provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
       useClass: SentryApiInterceptor,
    },
  ]
  controllers: [TestAppController],
})
export class TestAppModule {}
```

I have set up my handler for lambda like this:

```
let cachedServer: Server;

Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'my-dsn',
  debug: true,
});

async function bootstrapServer(): Promise<Server> {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    const expressApp = express();
    const nestApp = await NestFactory.create(
      TestAppModule,
      new ExpressAdapter(expressApp),
    );
    nestApp.use(eventContext());
    await nestApp.init();
    cachedServer = createServer(expressApp, undefined, undefined);
  }
  return cachedServer;
}

export const handler: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context) => {
  cachedServer = await bootstrapServer();
  return proxy(cachedServer, event, context, 'PROMISE').promise;
};
```

I deploy all this to AWS lambda, hook a gateway to it and start calling the endpoint.
Let's say I do 10 requests in row. 10 times I see in logs `sending error to sentry account` but if I go to Sentry then I see that this error is only sent there 3-9 times (differs across different tests). If I do exactly the same thing in local in a non-lambda environment then all 10 errors reach Sentry. But in lambda it's so unreliable.

I assume it's something to do with how Sentry flushes how and when it sends the errors to AWS. Maybe the lambda ends it's execution before the error is actually sent to Sentry? I tried to put `Sentry.flush(2000)` right after `Sentry.captureException(...)` but this did not help. I also tried some external NestJS modules built to integrate Sentry like https://github.com/mentos1386/nest-raven and https://github.com/ntegral/nestjs-sentry but they behaved exactly the same way. What can I do to make it work reliably?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to be consistent by using my middleware just like it was in the question and in addition to that wrapping the lambda in `Sentry.AWSLambda.wrapHandler`.

I am still not 100% sure why this helped but it seems it did. My theory is that the wrapper commits errors that could not be sent because lambda was already killed and the rest of them are sent by interceptor (because as it's a HTTP server sometimes the state is persisted). But maybe I'm totally off here.